# Contrapartidas en R Studio

Tags: python, r, rstudio, lógica, eliminar

Lo que busco es encontrar las filas en un conjunto de datos que representan transacciones contables. Cada transacción tiene un valor numérico "rpt_valor" y un código "codigo". Quiero identificar las transacciones que tienen contrapartes contables dentro del mismo grupo definido por "rpt_nombre_cliente" y "rpt_num_id".

Una contraparte contable es otra transacción que tiene el mismo valor numérico pero con signo opuesto en "rpt_valor" y "codigo", y que pertenece al mismo grupo "rpt_nombre_cliente" y "rpt_num_id". En otras palabras, una contraparte contable es una operación que cancela el efecto de la otra en términos contables.

Tengo la siguiente tabla de ejemplo:

| op_num_banco3 | rpt_tran | rpt_valor | rpt_nombre_cliente | rpt_concepto | rpt_num_id | codigo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0067CF0311179571 | 14875 | -105.877.383 | RAMIREZ LUIS | ANULACION POR CHEQUE DEVUELTO | 101016 | -14901 |
| 0067CF0311179571 | 14943 | -208.353.658 | RAMIREZ LUIS | DEVOLUCION REMANENTE POR CHEQUE DEVUELTO | 101016 | -14901 |
| 0067CF0311179571 | 14901 | 208.353.658 | RAMIREZ LUIS | APERTURA DPF | 101016 | 14901 |
| 0067CF0311179571 | 14901 | 105.877.383 | RAMIREZ LUIS | APERTURA DPF | 101016 | 14901 |
| 0067CF0311179571 | 14901 | 105.877.383 | RAMIREZ LUIS | APERTURA DPF | 101016 | 14901 |
| 0067CF0311224778 | 14901 | 105.877.383 | MAYORGA XIOMARA | APERTURA DPF | 1014567 | 14901 |
| 0067CF0311224778 | 14875 | 208.353.658 | RAMIREZ LUIS | ANULACION POR CHEQUE DEVUELTO | 101016 | -14901 |

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero dos tablas, una que se llame 'muertos' que tenga los datos de las que si tienen contrapartida es decir la siguiente tabla:

| op_num_banco3 | rpt_tran | rpt_valor | rpt_nombre_cliente | rpt_concepto | rpt_num_id | codigo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0067CF0311179571 | 14875 | -105.877.383 | RAMIREZ LUIS | ANULACION POR CHEQUE DEVUELTO | 101016 | -14901 |
| 0067CF0311179571 | 14943 | -208.353.658 | RAMIREZ LUIS | DEVOLUCION REMANENTE POR CHEQUE DEVUELTO | 101016 | -14901 |
| 0067CF0311179571 | 14901 | 208.353.658 | RAMIREZ LUIS | APERTURA DPF | 101016 | 14901 |
| 0067CF0311179571 | 14901 | 105.877.383 | RAMIREZ LUIS | APERTURA DPF | 101016 | 14901 |

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y otra que se llame 'vivos' y tenga los datos que no tienen contrapartida es decir lo siguientes:

| op_num_banco3 | rpt_tran | rpt_valor | rpt_nombre_cliente | rpt_concepto | rpt_num_id | codigo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0067CF0311179571 | 14943 | -208.353.658 | RAMIREZ LUIS | DEVOLUCION REMANENTE POR CHEQUE DEVUELTO | 101016 | -14901 |
| 0067CF0311179571 | 14901 | 208.353.658 | RAMIREZ LUIS | APERTURA DPF | 101016 | 14901 |
| 0067CF0311179571 | 14901 | 105.877.383 | RAMIREZ LUIS | APERTURA DPF | 101016 | 14901 |

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que intente fue lo siguiente:

```
# Encontrar las filas que cumplen las condiciones y tienen contrapartes (muertos)
muertos <- datos %>%
  inner_join(datos, by = c("rpt_nombre_cliente" = "rpt_nombre_cliente", "rpt_num_id" = "rpt_num_id")) %>%
  filter(rpt_valor.x == -rpt_valor.y, codigo.x == -codigo.y) %>%
  select(op_num_banco3 = op_num_banco3.x, 
         rpt_tran = rpt_tran.x, 
         rpt_valor = rpt_valor.x, 
         rpt_nombre_cliente, 
         rpt_concepto = rpt_concepto.x, 
         rpt_num_id)

# Encontrar las filas que cumplen las condiciones y no tienen contrapartes (vivos)
vivos <- datos %>%
  anti_join(muertos, by = c("op_num_banco3", "rpt_tran", "rpt_valor", "rpt_nombre_cliente", "rpt_concepto", "rpt_num_id", "codigo"))

#==========================================================
# y esto
# Identificar las filas con contrapartes contables
muertos <- datos %>%
  mutate(tiene_contraparte = rpt_valor %in% -rpt_valor & codigo %in% -codigo) %>%
  group_by(rpt_nombre_cliente, rpt_num_id, rpt_valor, codigo) %>%
  filter(sum(tiene_contraparte) == 2) %>%
  ungroup()

# Obtener la tabla "vivos" con las filas que no tienen contrapartes
vivos <- datos %>%
  filter(!(rpt_nombre_cliente %in% muertos$rpt_nombre_cliente & rpt_num_id %in% muertos$rpt_num_id))
```

Sin ningún resultado satisfactorio. Si alguien pudiera ayudarme o si se les ocurre alguna lógica para aplicar lo agradecería.

Comment: Buen día, ¿La solución que buscas es tanto en `Python` como en `R`? o ¿Por qué están las dos etiquetas?

Comment: Buen día en cualquiera de los dos lenguajes.